# Java/Kotlin generic list incompatible types with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have an abstract Java class with a concrete method that calls a method in the subclasses:

```
abstract class JavaSuperclass<T> {
    T doSomething() {
        ...
        return doSomethingInSubclass();
    }

    abstract T doSomethingInSubclass();
}
```

I have a Java subclass with its generic type set to a List:

```
class JavaSubclass extends JavaSuperclass<List<WhateverJava>> {
    List<WhateverJava> doSomethingInSubclass() {...}
}
```

And I have a Kotlin subclass:

```
class KotlinSubclass : JavaSuperclass<List<WhateverKotlin>> {
    override fun doSomethingInSubclass(): List<WhateverKotlin> {...}
}
```

(`WhateverJava` is a Java class, `WhateverKotlin` is a Kotlin data class.)

Then in a Java class I'm using both subclasses.

```
List<WhateverJava> listFromJava = javaSubclass.doSomething();
List<WhateverKotlin> listFromKotlin = kotlinSubclass.doSomething();
```

The line that calls the Java subclass compiles fine, but the one that calls the Kotlin subclass gives this error:

```
error: incompatible types: List<capture<? extends WhateverKotlin>> cannot be converted to List<WhateverKotlin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists in Kotlin are covariant. So the Kotlin class translates to Java as:

```
class KotlinSubclass extends JavaSuperclass<List<? extends WhateverKotlin>>
```

Adding a `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation to the Kotlin class fixes it.

```
class KotlinSubclass : JavaSuperclass<@JvmSuppressWildcards List<WhateverKotlin>> {
    override fun doSomethingInSubclass(): List<WhateverKotlin> {...}
}
```